# How do I increase the margin within a border using CSS3, so the border isn't so tightly wrapped?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a a div section that's styled like this:

```
.toppage {
border-style:double; 
border-width:3px;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Border at top of page]

Is there anything I can add to the CSS that would increase the space between the border and the elements inside it (e.g., the donate button), so that the border isn't hugging around the elements so tightly, and there's a little room to breathe?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: padding property my friend, padding

Comment: Have you tried adding padding to the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.toppage {
    border-style:double; 
    border-width:3px;
    padding : 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johny!  Appreciate you taking the time to respond!